# Python - sum the intersection of rows and columns in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix, sum

Let's suppose we have a matrix and a list of indexes:

```
adj_mat = np.array([[1,2,3],
                     [4,5,6],
                     [7,8,9]])
indexes = [0,2]
```

What I want is to sum the rows and columns corresponding to the sub matrix we get by the intersection of the rows and columns of the indexes list. In this case it would be:

```
 sub_matrix =  ([[1,3]
                 [7,9]])
 result_rows = [4,16]
 result_columns = [8,12]
```

However, I do this calculation rather a lot of times with the same original matrix and different indexes lists, so I am looking for an efficent solution without creating the sub matrix each iteration. My solution so far is (and for columns respectively):

```
def sum_rows(matrix, indexes):
    sum_r = [0]*len(indexes)
    for i in range(len(indexes)):
        for j in indexes:
            sum_r[i] += matrix.item(indexes[i], j)
    return sum_r
```

I'm looking for a more efficient algorithm as I remember there is a method which looks like this that sums all rows (or columns?) in the indexes:

```
matrix.sum(:, indexes)
matrix.sum(indexes, indexes)
```

I assume what I need is the second line, if it exists. I tried to google it, with or without numpy, but couldn't find the right syntax.

Is there a solution as I described here but I'm just using the wrong syntax? Or any other suggestions for improvement?

Comment: I don't understand the function `f` that takes `adj_mat` and `indexes` produces `sub_matrix`. How do you get `[[1, 6], [7, 9]]` from `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`? Also `[1, 3]` aren't indices of a 3 x 3 matrix. Do you mean `[0, 2]`?

Comment: Yes, I just made a human-like example not from the coding. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
import numpy as np

adj_mat = np.array([[1,2,3],
                    [4,5,6],
                    [7,8,9]])

indexes = np.array([1, 3]) - 1
sub_matrix = adj_mat[np.ix_(indexes, indexes)]
result_rows, result_columns = sub_matrix.sum(axis=1), sub_matrix.sum(axis=0)
```

Result:

```
array([ 4, 16]) # result_rows
array([ 8, 12]) # result_columns
```

Answer (score 1):

So assuming you made a mistake and you meant `indexes = [0,2]` and `sub_matrix = [[1,3], [7,9]]`, then this should do what you want

```
def sum_sub(matrix, indices):
    """
    Returns the sum of each row and column (as a tuple)
    for each index in indices (as an array)
    """
    # note that this sub matrix does not copy any data from matrix,
    # it is a "view" which simply holds a reference to matrix
    sub_mat = matrix[np.ix_(indices, indices)]
    return sub_mat.sum(axis=1), sub_mat.sum(axis=0)

sum_row, sum_col = sum_sub(np.arange(1,10).reshape((3,3)), [0,2])
```

The results of this are

```
sum_col  # --> [ 8 12]
sum_row  # --> [ 4 16]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the point of efficiency was brought up in the question, a little further analysis should probably be done.

First and foremost, the code looks like code to find a matrix inverse using the adjoint matrix. Unless that particular method is important to the project, the standard `np.linalg.inv()` is almost certainly going to be faster than anything we cook up here. Moreover, in many applications you can get away with solving a system of linear equations rather than finding an inverse and multiplying by it, cutting run times in half or more again.

Second, any discussion of efficient numpy code needs to address **views** as opposed to **copies**. Memory allocation, writing to memory, and memory deallocation are all extremely expensive operations when compared with standard floating point arithmetic. That's not to say that they're slow, but you can notice an order of magnitude or two of difference in the speed of code memory efficient code vs nearly anything else. That's the entire premise behind the fastest implementation of persistent homology calculations I know of, among other things.

All of the other answers (at the time of writing) create a **copy** of the data they're working with, explicitly storing that information in a new variable `sub_matrix`. It isn't possible to create every fancy-indexed matrix with a copy, but oftentimes equivalent operations can be performed.

For example, if this really is a set of computations on adjoint matrices so that your `indexes` variable consists of **all but one** of the available indices (in your example, all but the middle index), then instead of explicitly summing over all the intended indices, we can sum over all indices and subtract the one we don't care about. The effect is that all the intermediate matrices are **views** rather than **copies**, preventing the expensive memory allocations. On my machine, this is twice as fast for the tiny 3x3 example given and 10x as fast for 500x500 matrices.

```
bad_row = 1
bad_col = 1

result_rows = (np.sum(adj_mat, axis=1)-adj_mat[:,bad_col])[np.arange(adj_mat.shape[0])!=bad_row]
result_cols = (np.sum(adj_mat, axis=0)-adj_mat[bad_row,:])[np.arange(adj_mat.shape[1])!=bad_col]
```

Of course, it's even faster if you can use slices to represent whatever you're doing and you don't have to work around the problem with extra operations as I did, but the example you gave doesn't easily permit slices.

Comment: Thanks for the deatialed answer ! My calculations are not connected to  matrix inverse, but rather to calculations on dynamic subgraphs, and the degree of each subgraph. For that purpose to find the degrees of a subgraph I take the nodes that in it (rows) and check their neighbours only inside the subgraph (columns).
I see you have used the 'adj_mat[:,bad_row]'. Can't I just use it as 'adj_mat[good_columns,good_rows]' ?

Comment: Actually many times in the program I just move 1 node from a subgraph to another. In that case I need the sum of a specific row with the columns in indexes and vice versa. How would you do that? I guess a simple for loop would be sufficient for that task

Comment: @NaftaliWaxman To your first point, no `adj_mat[good_columns,good_rows]` doesn't in general return a view because that can't in general be **turned into a slice**. It works syntactically (I think), but it can't benefit from the efficiency gains of avoiding memory allocation. As to the second point I think I'm lacking details. It might be better dealt with as another question.